# Display value of slider with respect to slider thumb

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I want to move the label with respect to slider thumb just like this one:
[image]

Right now my slider is like this:

[image]

I want to display the label shown as 30 km with respect to the slider thumb such that as the slider moves, the label should move accordingly.

I am using Native React Slider component.

this is my code:

```
<Slider 
     style={styles.slider} 
     thumbTintColor='rgb(252, 228, 149)' 
     step={1} 
     maximumValue={5} 
     thumbTintColor='rgb(252, 228, 149)' 
     maximumTrackTintColor='#494A48' 
     minimumTrackTintColor='rgb(252, 228, 149)' />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution to your problem:

```
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            distance: 30,
            minDistance: 10,
            maxDistance: 100
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Slider
                    style={{ width: 300}}
                    step={1}
                    minimumValue={this.state.minDistance}
                    maximumValue={this.state.maxDistance}
                    value={this.state.distance}
                    onValueChange={val => this.setState({ distance: val })}
                    thumbTintColor='rgb(252, 228, 149)'
                    maximumTrackTintColor='#d3d3d3' 
                    minimumTrackTintColor='rgb(252, 228, 149)'
                />
                <View style={styles.textCon}>
                    <Text style={styles.colorGrey}>{this.state.minDistance} km</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.colorYellow}>
                        {this.state.distance + 'km'}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.colorGrey}>{this.state.maxDistance} km</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**Styles**:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#000',
    },
    textCon: {
        width: 320,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
    },
    colorGrey: {
        color: '#d3d3d3'
    },
    colorYellow: {
        color: 'rgb(252, 228, 149)'
    }
});
```

**Output**:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/telTT.jpg]

**Working Snippet:** 
https://snack.expo.io/Syrt3Bs7z

Comment: It works great but I want the label to move too as the slider mover. Here label is fixed at center

Comment: @AnkushRishi then why did you accept that answer...I am looking for the same boy

Answer (score 17):

You can adjust left of the text to the value of the slider.

```
const left = this.state.value * (screenWidth-60)/100 - 15;

<Text style={ { width: 50, textAlign: 'center', left: left } }>
  {Math.floor( this.state.value )}
</Text>

<Slider maximumValue={100} 
        value={this.state.value}
        onValueChange={value => this.setState({ value })} />
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply . if minimumValue = 3000 and maximumValue = 6000 what is the calculation for const left = .... ?

Answer (score 3):

Built in `<Slider />` doesn't provide those flexibility to customize what you want.

This should works, [react-native-slider](https://github.com/jeanregisser/react-native-slider), which is a drop-in replacement of official `<Slider />`.

What you need is very similar to it's demo style #4.

[image]

For your Slider Label of value, you can modify its function [_renderThumbImage()](https://github.com/jeanregisser/react-native-slider/blob/master/src/Slider.js#L503) to replace default `<Image />`.

Answer (score 0):

1. measure the size and position of the slider View

   ```
   <Slider
       maximumValue={10}
       onLayout={(event)=>{this.slider_bound(event)}}/>


   //majore size of Slider.
   slider_bound=(event)=>{
   var {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
   this.state.slider_Width=width;
   this.state.slider_Height=height;
   this.state.slider_x = x;
   this.state.slider_y = y;
   this.state.slider_x_step_size = width/10; //Devide the width by slider maximum value

   this.setState({triger:''});
   console.log(TAG+"Slider Dimen:"+width,height+'pos:',x,y);

   }
   ```

2.Now in "onValueChange" callback of slider.

```
   //compute position to show slider value txt
   this.state.value_x = (value * this.state.slider_x_step_size) + this.state.slider_x;
   this.state.value_y = this.state.slider_Height + this.state.slider_y;
```

3. Show the slider Value txt on Calculated positions.

   ```
   <Text style={{position:'absolute',top:this.state.value_y,left:this.state.value_x,color:colors.blackc}}>{this.state.data.slider_value}</Text>
   ```

..............
that will do the job, but You might have to tweak it little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think [react-native-multi-slider](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider) will solve your problem . You can change the slider thumb by sending your custom designed component to the `customMarker` prop that is available. Then you can wrap the `Multislider` in another component, maintain the state(for slider position value) there and send value as prop to your *custom designed marker* everytime the thumb position changes which can be detected using `onValuesChange` prop.

This [link](https://medium.com/@KPS250/custom-scale-slider-in-react-native-cb3e6ff786bd) might also help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Slider} from 'react-native-elements';    
<Slider
      thumbStyle={{height: 15, width: 15, backgroundColor: 'orange'}}
      maximumTrackTintColor="grey"
      minimumTrackTintColor="orange"
      thumbProps={{
        children: (
          <View
            style={{
              color: 'green',
              marginTop: -22,
              width: 100,
            }}>
            <Text>Text</Text>
          </View>
        ),
      }}
    />
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Building on the ahsan code,
i added Animated value, and wrapped the value in
Animated.View so it can animate properly

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Slider,Animated } from 'react-native';

const SliderComponent = () => {
  const minDistance = 10;
  const maxDistance = 100;

  const tooltipPosition = new Animated.Value(0);

  const updateTooltipPosition = (value) => {
    setDistance(value);
    tooltipPosition.setValue(value);
  };
  const [distance, setDistance] = useState(30);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Slider
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        step={1}
        minimumValue={minDistance}
        maximumValue={maxDistance}
        value={distance}
        onValueChange={(val) => updateTooltipPosition(val)}
        thumbTintColor='rgb(252, 228, 149)'
        maximumTrackTintColor='#d3d3d3'
        minimumTrackTintColor='rgb(252, 228, 149)'
      />
      <View style={styles.textCon}>
        <Text style={styles.colorGrey}>{minDistance} km</Text>
        <Animated.View
        style={[
          styles.bubble,
          { left: `${(distance / 100) * 90}%`, transform: [{ translateY: -10 }] },
        ]}
      >
        <Text style={[styles.colorYellow]}>{distance} km</Text>
      </Animated.View>
        <Text style={styles.colorGrey}>{maxDistance} km</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#000',
  },
  textCon: {
    width: 320,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  colorGrey: {
    color: '#d3d3d3',
  },
  colorYellow: {
    color: 'rgb(252, 228, 149)',
  },
  bubble: {
    position: 'absolute',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  bubbleText: {
    color: '#000000',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderRadius: 5,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
});

export default SliderComponent;
```

https://snack.expo.dev/@sahilkash/slider?platform=android