# How to have text following cursor with Slider in react native

Tags: react-native

I would like to have the text following the cursor with Slider in react-native but I don't know how to do that

I did that but it's not working, someone knows how to do that? thanks

```
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
 const left = value * (screenWidth - 60)/100 - 15;
```

```
          <Slider
            minimumValue={0}
            maximumValue={3}
            step={1}
            maximumTrackTintColor='rgb(44, 59, 142)' 
            minimumTrackTintColor='rgb(44, 59, 142)'
            onValueChange={value => setValue(value + 1)} 
            value={value}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const left = this.state.value * (screenWidth-60)/100 - 15;

<Text style={ { width: 50, textAlign: 'center', left: left } }>
  {Math.floor( this.state.value )}
</Text>

<Slider maximumValue={100} 
        value={this.state.value}
        onValueChange={value => this.setState({ value })} />
```

refrenence: [Display value of slider with respect to slider thumb react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089373/display-value-of-slider-with-respect-to-slider-thumb-react-native)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this but it's not working :/ and I used it with hooks

Comment: Well, can you get the value from slider? You can print the value in the console

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to fixed it :/

Comment: If you can get the current value from slider, then you can print the value with <Text> like above code. Please send the screenshot how your current app work

Comment: it's not working very well with   ```const left = (value *  (screenWidth - 60)) / 100 - 16;```